# Deploy separate web sites azure

Tags: azure

I have a single web project that I want deploy in Azure.

I want to create one IIS web site per country and I want to be able to deploy each web site independently (not all of them at a time). How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Well,
you have two options:

1. Use [Windows Azure WebSites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/) to host your websites
2. Use [Windows Azure Accelerator for WebRoles](https://github.com/microsoft-dpe/wa-accelerator-webroles) or your own project similar to that approach.

However you have to note that the second option is a project that is no longer being supported due to avialability of [Azure Websites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/). With Azure Websites, you can have almost everything you get with the Accelerator. You can host your websites on a dedicated instances, and manage them individually. You can update/deploy your website data via FTP/GIT/TFS/WebDeploy, whichever method you are most happy with. The only downside of websites which I see, is the lack of [Startup Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx) and the ability to customize your environment (Windows, IIS settings, etc).

Answer (score 0):

When you have set up your Azure account you can go the the web sites section and start the construction of your Azure web spaces, the interface in the preview is very straight forward to use and intuitive.

For deployment using the publish command in from Visual Studio 2012 (which I found the easiest) here are the steps you will need to undertake:

1. For each of your countries you will need to set up the web site
   in azure.
2. Then for each of those web sites you have created go
       to their dashboard page and download the publish profile settings.
3. It is these settings that you can import into you Visual Studio
       solution by selecting the publish command and browsing for the
       settings profile file you downloaded and importing it.
4. Then in future when
       you right click on the web site in your solution and select publish
       it will publish to your web site in Azure.

I have created a fictional website for Spain below is the link you will need in order to initiate a publish from Visual Studio.

[image: How to download the publish profile settings]

------------ EDIT -------------

For Visual Studio 2010 I met some difficulties trying to publish, in fact the publish profile you can download was not importable to Visual Studio 2010, well at least I could not figure it out.

Instead I created a deployment user by clicking on the 'Reset Deployment Credentials' link on the Azure dashboard (see the link in the image), created the user and then published via FTP from Visual Studio 2010.

**What I would like to flag up is the maintenance issue of having one site for each country rather than one site with Localization, (if it is a language issue). A small change multiplied just 20 times for 20 different countries becomes a larger task and if you have lots of little changes it soon becomes a large task to maintain them all.**

Comment: thanks, I'll try this, it seems the right answer. I'll mark as answered an soon I try this